# Video automatically stop after 8 to 10 minutes in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit, wpf-4.0

I am using Media element in wpf and playing a video in repeat behaviour but after some time my video doesn't play please suggest what i need to do so that my video never stop or hangs.
Code which i use is given below

Front End:-

```
  <MediaElement Name="myMediaElement" IsMuted="True" Stretch="Fill" Width="768" Height="500" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" LoadedBehavior="Manual">
                    <MediaElement.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MediaElement.Loaded">
                            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard SlipBehavior="Slip">

                                        <!-- The MediaTimeline has a RepeatBehavior="Forever" which makes the media play
                 over and over indefinitely.-->
                                        <MediaTimeline Name="videomediaTimeline" Storyboard.TargetName="myMediaElement"  
                                                RepeatBehavior="Forever" />

                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger.Actions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </MediaElement.Triggers>
                </MediaElement>
```

Code Behind:-

```
public MainGameWindow()
        {
            try
            {
                InitializeComponent();                
                myMediaElement.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(myMediaElement_Loaded);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

private void playVideoWithRepet()
        {
            try
            {
                string filePath = string.Empty;
                string _pathVedioRotater = _dynamicFilePath + "TopVideoRotate.xml";
                var doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(_pathVedioRotater);
                XmlNodeList setting = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Video");
                foreach (XmlNode item in setting)
                {
                    filePath = item.ChildNodes[2].InnerText.ToString();
                }

```
            string videopath = _dynamicFilePath + "TopContanerVideo/" + filePath;

            videomediaTimeline.Source = new Uri(videopath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);


            doc = null;
            _pathVedioRotater = null;
            filePath = string.Empty;
            videopath = null;
            setting = null;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }

    }
```